# Required box not appearing, Event Registration

Tags: registration

When I try to register event participants I receive a notification saying that I have not filled out three required fields. However, I cannot see or edit these required fields. Anyone know how to fix this? I am using version 4.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

you will get this error due to following reason -

- First if your Event registration is creating an New contact and if you have required field in your contact creation you will get this error message
- OR If you have some custom field created against Event and if those custom field are required fields then you will be getting these error message
- OR If you have any payment processor involved in your Event registration and if the address field are not field properly or card details are missing still you will get these error message

So just make sure you find the required field first and try to set some default value or include the fields in the event registration

If nothing helps please give some example - thanks

Comment: Here is a link to some screenshots of the issue: http://imgur.com/a/pm3hP

Comment: please try to register an Event using online registration (test drive)